# How to rename all columns between two sets of columns in a dataframe using R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I am interested in renaming columns across several datasets. The columns that need to be renamed vary by name and position, so they can't be selected that way. However, the columns prior to the columns I want to rename and the columns right after are constant.

As an example, say the `mpg` and `cyl` columns in `mtcars` are always the first two columns and their names never change. The `vs:carb` columns are similar, but their positions change depending on the number of columns added before them (but after `cyl`). However, the variable names from `hp:qsec` change and sometime a new variable will get added between them.

Say I want to append the word `'_Value'` to the end of each of the columns that are located after `cyl` and before `vs`. How would I go about doing that, ideally using `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  -

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  rename_with(~paste0(., '_Value'), -c(mpg:cyl, vs:carb)) %>%
  head

#                   mpg cyl disp_Value hp_Value drat_Value wt_Value qsec_Value vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6        160      110       3.90    2.620      16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6        160      110       3.90    2.875      17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4        108       93       3.85    2.320      18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6        258      110       3.08    3.215      19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8        360      175       3.15    3.440      17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6        225      105       2.76    3.460      20.22  1  0    3    1
```

If you have other columns in the data and to rename the columns specifically between `cyl` and `vs` you can do -

```
start <- match('cyl', names(mtcars))
end <- match('vs', names(mtcars))
cols <- (start + 1):(end - 1)
names(mtcars)[cols] <- paste0(names(mtcars)[cols], '_Value')
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I'm limited by an older version of dplyr. Is there an alternative to `rename_with` that I can use?

Comment: Yes, you can use `rename_at`  in the older version - `mtcars %>% rename_at(vars(-c(mpg:cyl, vs:carb)), ~paste0(., '_Value'))`